# Python - Program is returning None?

Tags: python

```
def tax(price):
    tax = None
    # YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    def tax(price):
        tax = None
    
        if price > 100000 :
            tax = (float(price * 20 / 100))
        elif price > 75000 and price <= 100000 :
            tax = (float(price * 15 / 100))
        elif price > 50000 and price <= 75000 :
            tax = (float(price * 10 / 100))
        else:
            tax = (float(price * 5 / 100))
        return tax

price = int(input())

print(tax(price))
```

Comment: `tax()` doesn't return anything it defines `tax` as `None` and then defines a function called `tax()` inside your function called `tax()` - and terminates, with the default return value of `None`

Comment: the tax in the inside i don't think its needed...

Answer (score 1):

You have a function called `tax` within the outer function called `tax`. The outer function returns nothing and the inner one is never called.
Remove the outer one to get the desired behaviour:

```py
def calculate_tax(price):
    if price > 100000 :
        tax = (float(price * 20 / 100))
    elif price > 75000 and price <= 100000 :
        tax = (float(price * 15 / 100))
    elif price > 50000 and price <= 75000 :
        tax = (float(price * 10 / 100))
    else:
        tax = (float(price * 5 / 100))
    return tax

price = int(input())
print(calculate_tax(price))
```

Comment: Another note is that this solution leaves the other problem OP introduced: shadowing their own function inside the function by introducing a variable that has the same name (`tax`). That can be intentional, but is generally best avoided. (directly returning would avoid it, or renaming it to something like `t`)  Not wrong, just worth noting for OP, to avoid forming bad habits.